# Hosted No-GUI VM reboots randomly

Tags: server, reboot

I will preface this by saying I only have a moderate exposure to Linux. I inherited a segment of Non-GUI Ubuntu servers running in a data center. One of these VMs has randomly rebooted (from what I can see) twice in the last 3 days.  When checking the the system for previous reboots I get this:

```
last reboot
reboot   system boot  3.16.0-29-generi Sun Mar 11 10:38 - 15:25 (1+04:47)
reboot   system boot  3.16.0-29-generi Fri Mar  9 09:37 - 15:25 (3+05:48)
```

How can I narrow down the cause of these reboots?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you receive any type of security updates?  Is your automatic update system enabled *and* configured to reboot for kernel updates and such?  If not, then check with the datacenter to see if they have specific backend logs that explain the reboots, as it's possible that the OS didn't handle the reboots but the nodes themselves did.  Note that a 'hosted' virtualized server is not going to have a clear-cut explanation for a reboot, as the host can do whatever they want.

Comment: I'm fairly confident this is an OS issue as the other VMs are not rebooting.  I will do some research and try to figure out the status of updating on that VM.

Comment: Check the `syslog`s, to see if anything called the reboot commands.  Random reboots are very hard to 'debug' because they could be caused by a lot of things.